# Asp.Net Core Session Variable Overridden

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net Core application. I have used session to keep track of objects a user may access. 
On one of the pages on the website, I have two lists that are loaded by JavaScript AJAX. When the IDs of the records for these lists are found, these IDs are then stored in a session variable as a serialized string (case from a list of ints).
These are 2 unique lists, with 2 unique session variables, lets call them List1 and List2. 
So it ends up with something like:

```
List1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
List2 = [100,101,102,103]
```

The problem is, as these two are called at the same time or in very quick succession via JS, it seems like the Session server side is being overridden by whichever is stored last.
I am using HttpContext.Session.SetString to set these.
I have tried using a setTimeout of a second, before calling the second list and that makes everything work, but that's not the most elegant or reliable. 
It seems as though the whole Session object is updated when the SetString is called and I end up losing the Session variable for one or another list.

Is there any way around this, or something I'm missing?

Thanks!

David

Comment: How are you saving the values to the Session object?

Comment: I pass the session context into my class like this   `public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }`  I then call it like this   `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("List1", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List1));`

Comment: Could you share us a demo to reproduce your issue? For `Session.SetString`, it should not affect other session values.

Comment: Hi @TaoZhou, Not sure how much more I can provide on this one. The JS is `$('#Table').load("/api/List1");` This controller retrieves a list, and then selects the primary keys which is then loaded as `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("List1", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List1));` This happens for a List1 and List2 at the same time, both called by JS and they appear to overwrite each other.